# converting flat json to nested

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

I have the following JSON

```
{
  "rate_cards": [
    {
      "doctor_id": "xxxxxx",
      "doctor_name": "Dr. Dre",
      "practice_id": "xxxxx",
      "is_owner": 0,
      "policy_id": 1,
      "policy_name": "GOLD Super Gold",
      "payor_id": 1,
      "payor_name": "AMEX",
      "payor_registration_number": "AMEX123",
      "payor_contact_email": "support@amex.com",
      "payor_support_number": "PHONE",
      "payor_logo_url": "url",
      "doctors_policies_ratecards_id": 1,
      "ratecard_activation_status": "Pending",
      "ratecard_id": 1,
      "ratecard_validity": "2017-04-17T13:16:58.000Z",
      "ratecard_details": "{'Root Canal': 300, 'Consultation': 500}",
      "onboarded_status": "Available"
    },
    {
      "doctor_id": xxxxxx,
      "doctor_name": "<NAME>",
      "practice_id": "xxxxxx",
      "is_owner": 0,
      "policy_id": 2,
      "policy_name": "GOLD Super Gold",
      "payor_id": 1,
      "payor_name": "AMEX",
      "payor_registration_number": "AMEX",
      "payor_contact_email": "support@amex.com",
      "payor_support_number": "<PHONE>",
      "payor_logo_url": "url",
      "doctors_policies_ratecards_id": 2,
      "ratecard_activation_status": "Pending",
      "ratecard_id": 1,
      "ratecard_validity": "2017-04-17T13:16:58.000Z",
      "ratecard_details": "{'Root Canal': 300, 'Consultation': 500}",
      "onboarded_status": "Available"
    }
  ]
}
```

and i want to convert it to

```
{
  "payors": [
      {
          "payor_id": 1,
          "payor_name": "AMEX",
          "payor_registration_number": "AMEX",
          "payor_contact_email": "support@amex.com",
          "payor_support_number": "<PHONE>",
          "payor_logo_url": "url",
          "data": [
              {
                  "doctor_id":xxxxx,
                  "doctor_name": "Dr. Dre",
                  "practice_id": xxxxxx,
                  "is_owner": 0,
                  "policy_id": 1,
                  "policy_name": "GOLD Super Gold",
                  "doctors_policies_ratecards_id": 1,
                  "ratecard_activation_status": "Pending",
                  "ratecard_id": 1,
                  "ratecard_validity": "2017-04-17T13:16:58.000Z",
                  "ratecard_details": "{'Root Canal': 300, 'Consultation': 500}",
                  "onboarded_status": "Available"
              }, 
              {
                  "doctor_id": xxxxxx,
                  "doctor_name": "name",
                  "practice_id": xxxxxxx,
                  "is_owner": 0,
                  "policy_id": 2,
                  "policy_name": "GOLD Super Gold",
                  "doctors_policies_ratecards_id": 2,
                  "ratecard_activation_status": "Pending",
                  "ratecard_id": 1,
                  "ratecard_validity": "2017-04-17T13:16:58.000Z",
                  "ratecard_details": "{'Root Canal': 300, 'Consultation': 500}",
                  "onboarded_status": "Available"
              }
          ]
      }
  ]
}
```

Basically i group by based on the `payor_name` and that becomes my primary reference nesting the structure. I tried using lodash groupBy and transform but was unable to achieve the above structure. Any sort of help on what i can do will be greatfull.

Comment: `payor_name` is different.

Comment: yes.. ```payor_name``` can be different in which case one more entry will go into the ```payors``` array with the same structure.

Comment: @NinaScholz edited the qn..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via lodash (skipped some keys, handle them) -

```js
var data = {
  "rate_cards": [
    {
      "doctor_id": "xxxxxx",
      "doctor_name": "Dr. Dre",
      "practice_id": "xxxxx",
      "is_owner": 0,
      "policy_id": 1,
      "policy_name": "GOLD Super Gold",
      "payor_id": 1,
      "payor_name": "Amex",
      "payor_registration_number": "AMEX123",
      "payor_contact_email": "support@amex.com",
      "payor_support_number": "PHONE",
      "payor_logo_url": "url",
      "doctors_policies_ratecards_id": 1,
      "ratecard_activation_status": "Pending",
      "ratecard_id": 1,
      "ratecard_validity": "2017-04-17T13:16:58.000Z",
      "ratecard_details": "{'Root Canal': 300, 'Consultation': 500}",
      "onboarded_status": "Available"
    },
    {
      "doctor_id": "xxxxx",
      "doctor_name": "<NAME>",
      "practice_id": "xxxxxx",
      "is_owner": 0,
      "policy_id": 2,
      "policy_name": "GOLD Super Gold",
      "payor_id": 1,
      "payor_name": "AMEX",
      "payor_registration_number": "AMEX",
      "payor_contact_email": "support@amex.com",
      "payor_support_number": "<PHONE>",
      "payor_logo_url": "url",
      "doctors_policies_ratecards_id": 2,
      "ratecard_activation_status": "Pending",
      "ratecard_id": 1,
      "ratecard_validity": "2017-04-17T13:16:58.000Z",
      "ratecard_details": "{'Root Canal': 300, 'Consultation': 500}",
      "onboarded_status": "Available"
    }
  ]
};

var newdata = _.reduce(data.rate_cards,
    function( arr, item){
      var index = _.findIndex(arr, { "payor_id" : item.payor_id});
      if(index > -1){
        arr[index].data.push(item);
      } else {
        arr.push({ "payor_id" : item.payor_id, "data" : [item] });
      }
     return arr;
    },
    []
    );
    
console.log({ "payors" : newdata});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: found this to be the most elegant

Answer (score 1):

I iterate over rate_cards adding payors to my dictionary indexed by id. For each payor I add the rest of the object to the data array.

After that loop I convert my dictionary into an array and print the result.

```js
const input = {
  "rate_cards": [{
      "doctor_id": "xxxxxx",
      "doctor_name": "Dr. Dre",
      "practice_id": "xxxxx",
      "is_owner": 0,
      "policy_id": 1,
      "policy_name": "GOLD Super Gold",
      "payor_id": 1,
      "payor_name": "Amex",
      "payor_registration_number": "AMEX123",
      "payor_contact_email": "support@amex.com",
      "payor_support_number": "PHONE",
      "payor_logo_url": "url",
      "doctors_policies_ratecards_id": 1,
      "ratecard_activation_status": "Pending",
      "ratecard_id": 1,
      "ratecard_validity": "2017-04-17T13:16:58.000Z",
      "ratecard_details": "{'Root Canal': 300, 'Consultation': 500}",
      "onboarded_status": "Available"
    },
    {
      "doctor_id": "xxxxxx",
      "doctor_name": "<NAME>",
      "practice_id": "xxxxxx",
      "is_owner": 0,
      "policy_id": 2,
      "policy_name": "GOLD Super Gold",
      "payor_id": 1,
      "payor_name": "AMEX",
      "payor_registration_number": "AMEX",
      "payor_contact_email": "support@amex.com",
      "payor_support_number": "<PHONE>",
      "payor_logo_url": "url",
      "doctors_policies_ratecards_id": 2,
      "ratecard_activation_status": "Pending",
      "ratecard_id": 1,
      "ratecard_validity": "2017-04-17T13:16:58.000Z",
      "ratecard_details": "{'Root Canal': 300, 'Consultation': 500}",
      "onboarded_status": "Available"
    }
  ]
};

const payors = new Map();

function isPayorProperty(value, key) {
  return key.indexOf('payor') === 0;
}

for (const card of input.rate_cards) {
  if (!payors.has(card.payor_id)) {
    payors.set(card.payor_id, _.assign({
      data: []
    }, _.pickBy(card, isPayorProperty)));
  }

  const payor = payors.get(card.payor_id);
  payor.data.push(_.pickBy(card, _.negate(isPayorProperty)));
}

const output = {
  "rate_cards": []
};

for (const payor of payors) {
  output.rate_cards.push(payor[1]);
}

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In plain Javascript, you could use a hash table as reference to the same grouping item and separate the data with lookup if the prefix `payor` and take the one with for grouping data and the rest for the relevant data.

```js
var data = { rate_cards: [{ doctor_id: "xxxxxx", doctor_name: "Dr. Dre", practice_id: "xxxxx", is_owner: 0, policy_id: 1, policy_name: "GOLD Super Gold", payor_id: 1, payor_name: "AMEX", payor_registration_number: "AMEX123", payor_contact_email: "support@amex.com", payor_support_number: "PHONE", payor_logo_url: "url", doctors_policies_ratecards_id: 1, ratecard_activation_status: "Pending", ratecard_id: 1, ratecard_validity: "2017-04-17T13:16:58.000Z", ratecard_details: "{'Root Canal': 300, 'Consultation': 500}", onboarded_status: "Available" }, { doctor_id: "xxxxxx", doctor_name: "<NAME>", practice_id: "xxxxxx", is_owner: 0, policy_id: 2, policy_name: "GOLD Super Gold", payor_id: 1, payor_name: "AMEX", payor_registration_number: "AMEX", payor_contact_email: "support@amex.com", payor_support_number: "<PHONE>", payor_logo_url: "url", doctors_policies_ratecards_id: 2, ratecard_activation_status: "Pending", ratecard_id: 1, ratecard_validity: "2017-04-17T13:16:58.000Z", ratecard_details: "{'Root Canal': 300, 'Consultation': 500}", onboarded_status: "Available" }] },
    result = { payors: [] };

data.rate_cards.forEach(function (hash) {
    return function (o) {
        var temp = { payor: {}, data: {} };
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            temp[k.match(/^payor/) || 'data'][k] = o[k];
        });
        if (!hash[o.payor_name]) {
            temp.payor.data = [];
            hash[o.payor_name] = temp.payor;
            result.payors.push(hash[o.payor_name]);
        }
        hash[o.payor_name].data.push(temp.data);
    };
}(Object.create(null)));
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```